# Create bash script that takes input

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line, terminal

I want to create a bash script that is simular to a programming interpreter like `mongo`, `node`, `redis-cli`, `mysql`, etc.

I want to be able to use a command like `test` and it behave like the examples above.

```
thomas@workstation:~$ test
>
```

How do I make a command that behaves like this? What is this called?

I want to be able to take the content and turn it into a variable.

```
thomas@workstation:~$ test
> hello world
hello world 
thomas@workstation:~$
```

I only want to take one "entry" after enter is pressed once I want to be able to process the string "hello world" in the code, like echo it.

What is this called? How do I make one using BASH?

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)

Comment: Why not just implement your desired commands as scripts (or shell functions in a single script)?  Bash is already a very powerful environment & does a great job of, you know, *being a shell.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key word that might be useful here is `REPL` (Read–eval–print loop) used primarily for programming languages or coding environments. Your browsers console is a great example of a `REPL`.

[Node allows you use their REPL to build interactive apps.](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think "read" is what you are looking for, isn't it?

here is a link with some examples: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Getting_User_Input_Via_Keyboard

so you can do stuff like this:

```
read -p "Enter your name : " name
echo "Hi, $name. Let us be friends!"
```

Comment: I understand that commands can take flags and arguments I wanted to understand how the alternative works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry this doesn't answer you directly, but it might be worth it to look into using a more fully capable programming language such as Python, Ruby, or Perl for a task like this. In Python you can use the raw_input() function.

```
user_command = raw_input('> ')
```

would yield your prompt.

Comment: "Prompt" is a great word thanks for that. I see that bash also might be insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

First, do not name your script `test`.  That generates too much confusion.  Whatever you call it, you can do many things:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '> '
read line
echo "$line"
```

If your shell supports it:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -p '> ' line
echo "$line"
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '> '
sed 1q    # This will print the input.  To store in in a variable: a=$( sed 1q )
```

Comment: I knew I was going to get flac for naming that example `test`, thanks for your submission. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
[spatel@tux ~]$ read a
Hello World!!!!!
[spatel@tux ~]$ echo $a
Hello World!!!!!
```